# Changing date-time format in c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, time, clock

Creating digital clock. I'm newbie to C#. My code look like that

```
    timeLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    dateLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
```

Here is, the result

http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/da6d1f65-bf5f-4735-97dc-70485112a998/2012-07-02_1826.png

I got some questions:

1. Can I change time's format to 24 Hour? how?
2. How to change date into digits only format (like dd/mm/yyyy) or this result but in exact language (I mean, words "Monday, July" in another language, which windows support, for ex Turkish)?
3. How to make window dynamically change it's width (depending on text
   length)?

Please help me,to achieve these 3 things. Thx in advance

Comment: Please do some research - these are basic questions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans 1:

```
timeLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Will convert time to 24 hour format.

Ans 2:

```
dateLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Will convert date format to `31/06/2012`

More formats [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: timeLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:SS");
            dateLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"); I did it, but time doesn't tick any more, and seconds shows as "SS" NOT ACTUAL SECONDS

Comment: Where have you seen time formatted by slash? And it's same problem it shows "SS" instead of seconds, and time not ticking

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/WYEZyDVbR

Answer (score 1):

The first and second point where been answered, for the last point set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the window and the window will dynamically resize based on its content size. I assume ur working with wpf, else it doesnt works!

Comment: timeLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM:SS"); dateLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"); I did it, but time doesn't tick any more, and seconds shows as "SS" not actual seconds